# Is $a$ assigned to $b$ or is $b$ assigned to $a$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Being very interested in relations, functions and the best way on how to teach them at a set theoretic level, the following is something that has begun to puzzle me.

#### **Relations**

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Now, let $R \subset A \times B$ be a binary relation from the set $A$ to the set $B$. I have been reading the following [article](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Epkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/s7_1.pdf) on relations to not only further my education on them, but also put together a *study guide* for anyone who is new to set theory and wants a solid foundation. As I was reading, I came across the following remark:

“*Notice that a relation is simply a subset of $A \times B$. If $(a,b) \in R$, where $R$ is some relation from $A$ to $B$, **we think of $a$ as being assigned to $b$**.*”   $(1)$

Now, I didn’t think too much about the idea of an element $a$ being assigned to an element $b$ By the relation $R$. The reason being is that this appeared synonymous with if $(a,b) \in R$ then $a$ is related to $b$ (by definition of a relation). However, I began to think about it more when I read about functions in another source.

#### Functions

Upon reading this [article](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/RF.pdf) about functions in order to extend my citations, I came across the following remark after the definition of a function was stated. Just know that $f: A \to B$ such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$:

*”It is common usage to say “$f$ maps $A$ to $B$”. This expression arises from the usual arrow diagram where each element of $A$ is joined by an arrow to the element of $B$ assigned to it. Unfortunately, this tends to lead to the confusion that **the elements of $A$ are somehow assigned to the elements of $B$, which is backwards!** **It is the elements of $B$ that are assigned to the elements of $A$**.*”       $(2)$

As you can see the bolded statement in remark $(2)$ is the opposite of the bolded statement in remark $(1)$. With that said:

Which is correct to say? Is an element $a$ assigned to an element $b$, or is an element be $b$ assigned to an element $a$?

I think what has stumped me on this is that in the definition of a function, we see the vernacular “$a$ is mapped to $f(a)$”. So, naturally I have always believed it was the bolded portion of remark $(1)$ that was correct; as it seemed too similar to be wrong. Not to mention, along with the definition of a relation that you learn first before functions: “if $(a,b) \in R$ then $a$ is related to $b$“.

The only other time I have seen a *variation* of the bolded portion of remark $(2)$ is in the following definition of a function in some textbooks and lecture notes: *for all $a \in A$ there is assigned a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.*

Please give an in depth answer and not just an opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a professional mathematician who has taught set theory, this is my answer:

In the context of a general relation, I would never use the word "assigned" (in either direction). The fact that any $a\in A$ can be related to many $b\in B$, and any $b\in B$ can have many $a\in A$ related to it, makes the word "assigned" sound off-the-mark to me.

For example, $<$ is a perfectly good relation on $\Bbb N$. Does it sound right to say "under the less-than relation, $1$ is assigned to $2$, and $1$ is also assigned to $3$, and $2$ is assigned to $3$, ..."? Not to me.

In the context of a function, I would probably avoid the word "assigned" as well. Mathematically my instinct is to say that the function values in the codomain $B$ are assigned to the elements of the domain $A$. But on the other hand, in real-life examples of functions such as "every student is assigned to an advisor", the usage is that elements of the domain (students) are assigned to elements of the codomain (advisors).

The mathematical (set-theoretic) definitions of relation and function are unambiguous, and so the question of what "assigned" means is not crucial to their definitions—it's a question of how we discuss their definitions in English. Simply avoiding the word "assigned" altogether solves the problem without losing any ability to work with functions and relations.

Answer (score 1):

- Sometimes, one reads " function *f* sends/maps/associates  *a* to *b*" .
- Maybe the " assigns" phrasing is misleading, but you will find it in logic. In propositional logic, an " interpretation" is defined as a function from the set of all atomic sentences to the set $\{T,F\}$. It is said to be a " truth value assignment": an interpretation is a functon that assigns a truth value to each atomic sentence of the ( propositional calculus) language.
- As you can see here ***it is the output that is assigned to the input*** ( not the other way round).
- Whatever term one may use, the key thing is to understand that the relation, by itself,  is one-way: sayng that $a$ is related to $b$ , or that $(a,b)\in R$ does not imply, by itself, that $b$ is related to $a$.

Comment: So is it correct to say a relation assigns an element in the domain an element in the codomain (or, possibly, more than one element in codomain)?

Comment: I think the " assignment" phrasing is more common in the context of relations that are also functions. In logic , as I said, one can say that , in a given interpretation " the value True is assigned to  proposition $P_1$, and the value False is assigned to proposition $P_2$ ", etc. So a given output is assigned to a given input ( the input " receives" so to say , a given value).

Comment: In the context of relations that are not functions, one commonly reads : " element $a$ in set A  is related , by relation $R$, to element $b$ in set $B$ ", which is written : $aRb$ or $ (a,b)\in R$. So , $R$ *relates* $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense.

Comment: You are welcome.